# D3 Ordinal Scale: Map multiple domain values to same range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently use the D3 ordinal scale like so:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
  .range(['#00986F', '#41A5D1', '#695998', '#CD5053']);
```

There are a couple additional domain values that I would like to map to 'colors' which already exist in my range. I could accomplish this like so:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y'])
  .range(['#00986F', '#41A5D1', '#695998', '#CD5053', '#00986F', '#CD5053']);
```

My question, is there another way to map multiple domain values to the same range output without repeating the desired range value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in this case you have to repeat the values. If your domain was numeric, you could use a quantize scale or something similar, but for ordinal values you have to repeat.